# Pre-bundle software on my ubuntu USB boot stick

Tags: boot, usb, games

**Is it possible to pre-bundle software on an USB-boot stick so that it installs automatically when formatting the computer?**

I have a computer that is going to be donated to the student communtity "Fysikkforeningen" (Physics community) at the University of Oslo. I'm installing Ubuntu as the main OS, and a bunch of programming tools and game emulators (nintendo, playstation, gamecube etc). The computer is going to be available for anyone to use, and therefore i need to have a bootable USB to reformat the computer when it becomes slow and cluttered. Making a bootable USB is no problem, but it would be nice to have the software automatically installed and set up. Does anyone know how to make such an USB-stick?

Would it be possible to install software directy to the USB, and have it "burned" to the hdd whenever i format?

The main purpose of this computer is to serve as an old-school gaming platform, not a homework station, we have other computers for that. But since we get Matlab and other expencive tools for free, it would be nice put it on there, and not re-install everything manually whenever we need to format the computer.

Best Regards,

Einar
Fysikkforeningen, University of Oslo

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to customize a Ubuntu Installation DVD using [Ubuntu Customization Kit](http://sourceforge.net/projects/uck/). It allows you to add drivers, packages, applications and language packs. All the added packages will be automatically installed on OS install.

Install it with:

```
sudo apt-get install uck
```